# Ionic project proxy/vpn settings

Tags: android, proxy, ionic-framework, vpn

I have an ionic project that I require the user of this project at a certain point to run over a specific VPN/Proxy, and to be protected under that proxy settings. Any ideas how I can resolve that issue or where to start from ?

Thanks